# How to create an edge preserving blur (similar to a bilateral filter) using a limited set of primitive operations

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, svg

I have been attempting to duplicate a bilateral filter effect (edge preserving, color-range aware) using the limited set of primitives in the existing toolbox of SVG filters. I've tried a number of approaches. My most successful to date is a three part operation that does Sobel edge detection, dilates the Sobel edges, extracts the pixels corresponding to those edges with a compositing operation, gaussian blurs the source image and then composites back the original edge pixels on top of the blurred image. The result preserves edges, but is not color-range aware.

```
<filter id="surfaceBlur" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <!-- convert source image to luminance map-->
        <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" />
        <!-- sober edge detection-->
        <feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 -2 -1  
                                                    0 0 0  
                                                   1 2 1 "
                          preserveAlpha="true"
                         />
        <feConvolveMatrix order="3" kernelMatrix="-1 0 1  
                                                  -2 0 2 
                                                  -1 0 1 "
                          preserveAlpha="true"
                          />
      <!-- dilate the edges to produce a wider mask-->
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"
                     result="mask"/>
      <!-- extract just the detail from the source graphic using the dilated edges -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic" in2="mask" result="detail" />
      <!-- blur the source image -->
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" in="SourceGraphic" result="backblur"/>
       <!-- slap the detail back on top of the blur! -->
      <feComposite operator="over" in="detail" in2="backblur"/>
```

You can see the original, a gaussianBlur, this filter and in the bottom right, a true bilateral filter:

http://codepen.io/mullany/details/Dbyxt

As you can see, it's not an awful result, but it's not very close to a bilateral filter. This method also only works with greyscale images because it uses luminance differences to find edges - so edges between colors of similar luminance are not detected.

So the question is whether there is a algorithm variant of an edge preserving color range aware filter (guided edge view, bilateral etc.) - that can be constructed using the limited primitives available in SVG - which for those not familiar with SVG are:

- gaussian blur
- convolution (any kernel size)
- erode/dilate
- color matrix
- all porter duff compositing operations
- basic blending ops (multiply, screen, lighten, darken)
- a component transfer primitive that allows color channels to be transformed with a table lookup (as well as floored/ceilinged to specific values)

Only the RGB color space is available. Multiple iterations are fine, and any directed graph of these operations can be constructed.

Update:

I successfully created a median filter using feBlend lighten and darken as Max and Min operators in a bubble sort (thanks to help from cs.stackexchange.com). However this is inefficient: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/dmbvz, and lacks the color range awareness of a bilateral filter.

Comment: You could always suggest adding additional filters to  http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/ Firefox and Chrome are implementing features from this specification right now.

Comment: Yes Robert, I have a long email I'm composing for what is needed wrt filters, now that custom filters have been cancelled.

Answer (score 5):

I should qualify this by saying I have no experience in graphics whatsoever, but from a maths perspective I think this would work to emulate [the equation that defines the bilateral filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter):

- Given your image `I`, use the color matrix to produce an image `Intensity` which holds the intensity of each pixel in a single channel, say R. Channels G and B are zeroed out.
- For each non-central pixel in your bilateral filter window, construct a convolution matrix which takes the difference between the specific pixel and the central pixel. For example, for a 3x3 window you'd have matrices

  ```
   0 0 0   -1 0 0    0-1 0    0 0-1    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0        
  -1 1 0    0 1 0    0 1 0    0 1 0    0 1-1    0 1 0    0 1 0    0 1 0    
   0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0-1    0-1 0   -1 0 0
  ```

  You can scale the `1`s and `-1`s here as necessary to emulate the spatial kernel of the bilateral filter.
- Apply each convolution matrix to the `Intensity` map, getting (in the 3x3 example) 8 images which represent the change in intensity between a central pixel and its neighbours.
- For each of the 8 images, apply a component transfer primative to R with a table that emulates the range kernel of the bilateral filter.
- Use another color matrix to set the G and B channels to match the R channel in all 8 images.
- Use the multiply operator on each of the 8 and the original image to get 8 new images which represent the 8 terms in the bilateral filter's sum.
- Use the Porter-Duff operators to superimpose the 8 images, effectively taking a sum of the 8 terms in the bilateral filter. This gives you the final image.

Comment: Hi - Andy just a quick clarification on step 5 ("Use another color matrix..") Do you mean repeat the steps we just did for the R channel with G and B?

Comment: Either repeat the steps, or just copy the R channel over to the G and B channels.

Comment: Thinking about it now, I'm not entirely clear on how multiplying two pixels together works. Does it just multiply the values in each channel? Might need to add a normalization step as well, I'm not sure. Does the approach as a whole make sense to you?

Comment: yes SVG multiply multiplies the unitized values of each pixel's value per channel. I'm coding the approach up right now. I'm not entirely sure how to emulate the range kernel with a table, but I'm going to give it a shot

Comment: Yeah, you've just made me realize that with my naive idea to store both the intensity value and the color value as a number 0-255, a straight multiplication is going to give some serious overflow issues. The easy solution of scaling both so intensity can range from say 0-15 and colour can range from 0-16 doesn't seem very appealing either. Hmm.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Did you figure out a solution to how to multiple them without overflow? I've been pondering it on and off for a few days and haven't got anywhere.

Comment: Oh! Cool. Like I said, not a damned clue about graphics. Glad it worked out :)

Comment: I tried implementing this today and got a perfect copy of the original image at the end, so I'm trying other variants of your approach to see whether I can poke SVG just right to release the candy.

Answer (score 1):

The following document explains how to implement a constant time approximation of the bilateral filter using interpolation of spatial filters at different pixel intensity levels (interpolation + gaussian filters only):

[Qingxiong Yang, Kar-Han Tan and Narendra Ahuja, Real-time O(1) Bilateral Filtering,
IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR) 2009]

A java implementation exists here: https://code.google.com/p/kanzi/source/browse/java/src/kanzi/filter/FastBilateralFilter.java

To see the results of the filter:

`java -cp kanzi.jar kanzi.test.TestEffects -filter=FastBilateral -file=...`

The original C code and other goodies are available at http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~qiyang

Comment: I tried a variant of this approach (chopping up the image into luminance buckets and applying spatial kernels to each range and then blending the results). Unfortunately, it seems to require a lot of ranges to be effective - my trial with 8 buckets resulted in a fairly creepy cat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using purely Image Processing : -

1. Use Unsharp masking (It basically sharpens the edges).

   [Unsharp Masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking)

   It can be done by adding the laplacian of original image to original image.
2. Use blurring on sharpened image.

The concept behind it is that as blurring reduces intensity of edges as well, so we increase the intensity of all sharp edges and then apply blurring that neutralizes the effect.

**Note:**- I have No idea of SVG masking

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer has already been accepted and bounty rewarded, I would like to try the [anisotropic diffusion algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion). It applies the law of diffusion on pixel intensities to smooth textures in the image. Diffusion to occurs across edges is prevented, and therefore it preserves edges in the image. 
I am not very familiar with SVG, and just wrote a very simple code in Matlab on gray scale image. But I assume it is feasible in SVG because only basic difference operations (difference between the pixel `i+1` and `i`, in all the 4 directions) and power/adding operations are required. 
The code:

```
diff = I; % original image
lambda = 0.25; 
niter = 10;
Co = 20;
for i = 1:niter  % iterations

  % Construct diffl which is the same as diff but
  % has an extra padding of zeros around it.
  diffl = zeros(rows+2, cols+2);
  diffl(2:rows+1, 2:cols+1) = diff;

  % North, South, East and West differences
  deltaN = diffl(1:rows,2:cols+1)   - diff;  
  deltaS = diffl(3:rows+2,2:cols+1) - diff;  
  deltaE = diffl(2:rows+1,3:cols+2) - diff;  
  deltaW = diffl(2:rows+1,1:cols)   - diff;

  cN = 1./(1 + (deltaN/Co).^2);
  cS = 1./(1 + (deltaS/Co).^2);
  cE = 1./(1 + (deltaE/Co).^2);
  cW = 1./(1 + (deltaW/Co).^2);

  diff = diff + lambda*(cN.*deltaN + cS.*deltaS + cE.*deltaE + cW.*deltaW);

end
```

The result image I obtained:

[image]

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Sadly, power ops are not available in SVG Filters - it's a weirdly constrained toolbox - hence the original question.

Comment: Then you may just use multiplication on each pixel and obtain xi * xi